# load images into bootstrap carousel onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-carousel

I'm working on an html site with a lot of images, to reduce loading time I'm going to load hidden images when user click on the cover image with javascript, then insert it into bootstrap carousel.

I tried to make it, but unsuccessful. Images aren't load. Any help? 
Here is my last code:

**HTML**

```
<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="imgFilter('.ar-img')">
    <img src="images/AR/01.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <div class="accordion carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/AR/01.jpg" alt="slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="ar-img" src="" data-src="images/AR/02.jpg" alt="slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="ar-img" src="" data-src="images/AR/03.jpg" alt="slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="imgFilter('.br-img')">
    <img src="images/BR/01.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <div class="accordion carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/BR/01.jpg" alt="slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="br-img" src="" data-src="images/BR/02.jpg" alt="slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="br-img" src="" data-src="images/BR/03.jpg" alt="slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

JS

```
function imgFilter(id) {
    var imgId = $(id);

    $("imgId").each(function(i) {
        $("this").setAttribute('src', $("this").getAttribute('data-src'));
    });
};
```

Comment: Do not use one same id on different elements on the same page. it is forbidden!!! instead use class.

Comment: @FarzadYZ, thanks. updated

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of:

```
$(".item img").each(function(i) {
    $("this").setAttribute('src', $("this").getAttribute('data-src'));
}
```

however i would use jQuery plugin lazyload instead (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

---

Assumed you have css like:

```
.item{
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
}
.item img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work, I got n.fn.init[1],
updated the JS code,
lazyload needs the img height & width, for some reason I can't set the img height & width